# ClassNotFoundException: com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyNullLogger

Tags: java, gwt, jboss, jetty, errai

I am using GWT 2.7 , Errai 3.1.1 Final. I would like to run Errai+GWT sample project with Dev mode of Eclipse. I added program argument as `-server org.jboss.errai.cdi.server.gwt.JettyLauncher`.

My pom.xml file was referenced from [here](https://github.com/errai/errai/blob/master/errai-demos/errai-cdi-demo-mvp/pom.xml). When I run I got below error at my console.

```
Unable to load server class 'org.jboss.errai.cdi.server.gwt.JettyLauncher'java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.errai.cdi.server.gwt.JettyLauncher
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode$ArgHandlerServer.setString(DevMode.java:177)
at com.google.gwt.util.tools.ArgHandlerString.handle(ArgHandlerString.java:26)
at com.google.gwt.util.tools.ToolBase.processArgs(ToolBase.java:250)
at com.google.gwt.dev.ArgProcessorBase.processArgs(ArgProcessorBase.java:30)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:412)
Google Web Toolkit 2.7.0
DevMode [-[no]startServer] [-port port-number | "auto"] [-whitelist whitelist-string] [-blacklist blacklist-string] [-logdir directory] [-logLevel level] [-gen dir] [-bindAddress host-name-or-address] [-codeServerPort port-number | "auto"] [-[no]superDevMode] [-server servletContainerLauncher[:args]] [-startupUrl url] [-war dir] [-deploy dir] [-extra dir] [-modulePathPrefix ] [-workDir dir] [-XmethodNameDisplayMode NONE | ONLY_METHOD_NAME | ABBREVIATED | FULL] [-sourceLevel [auto, 1.6, 1.7]] [-XjsInteropMode [NONE, JS, CLOSURE]] [-[no]incremental] module[s]
```

---

**Edit :** Now I add below dependency to fix it

```
    <dependency>  
     <groupId>org.jboss.errai</groupId>  
     <artifactId>errai-cdi-jetty</artifactId>
     <version>2.4.5.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

but another error has appeared as below

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gwt/dev/shell/jetty/JettyNullLogger
at org.jboss.errai.cdi.server.gwt.JettyLauncher.<clinit>(JettyLauncher.java:558)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode$ArgHandlerServer.setString(DevMode.java:177)
at com.google.gwt.util.tools.ArgHandlerString.handle(ArgHandlerString.java:26)
at com.google.gwt.util.tools.ToolBase.processArgs(ToolBase.java:250)
at com.google.gwt.dev.ArgProcessorBase.processArgs(ArgProcessorBase.java:30)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:412)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyNullLogger
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
... 8 more
```

I don't know what is this and how to fix it.

Comment: @SamwiseGamgee No sir, I use run as >Web Application (GWT Super Dev mode).

Comment: this is the list of jars which contains this class http://www.findjar.com/class/com/google/gwt/dev/shell/jetty/JettyNullLogger.html

Comment: @SamwiseGamgee Yes sir , I imported ***gwt-dev-2.7.0*** but this error not satisfy yet.

Comment: Hey from this code I gues you are using maven :    <dependency>  
     <groupId>org.jboss.errai</groupId>  
     <artifactId>errai-cdi-jetty</artifactId>
     <version>2.4.5.Final</version>
    </dependency> do you clean and install your project, before you run it?

Answer (score 0):

I simply implemented the missing class `public class JettyNullLogger implements org.mortbay.log.Logger` (assuming a null-logger is not supposed to do much...) in my workspace and it seems to work out.

The subsequent exception was `java.lang.IllegalStateException: No such servlet: javax.ws.rs.core.Application`.
So I added jetty's default implementation of javax.ws.rs.core.Application to web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Rest</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Rest</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

This required to add

```
compile 'com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:1.+'
compile 'com.sun.jersey:jersey-server:1.+'
compile 'com.sun.jersey:jersey-servlet:1.+'
```

to the classpath.